# Typescript declaration merging: override?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Is there a way to "override" when doing declartion merge, eg:

app.ts (express + nodejs):

```
import * as express from 'express';
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers.accept);
});
```

This fails with error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'accept' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
```

Because in express.d.ts headers are declared like this:

```
headers: { [key: string]: string; };
```

So what i've tried to do, is create a definition of 'accept' :

```
declare module Express {
  export interface Headers {
    accept: String
  }
  export interface Request {
    headers: Headers
  }
}
```

But that does not work also (i can only add new members, not override them, right?):

```
    error TS2430: Interface 'e.Request' incorrectly extends interface 'Express.Request'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type '{ [key: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers'.
      Property 'accept' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
```

So the only way to overcome this is change notation to:

```
req.headers.accept -> req.headers['accept']
```

Or i somehow can "redeclare" the headers property?

Comment: Which "express.d.ts" file are you using ?

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Express, you can use the `accepts` method ([accepts documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.accepts)):

```
if (req.accepts('json')) { //...
```

Or if you want them all, they are available as:

```
console.log(req.accepted);
```

To get other headers, use the `get` method ([get method documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get))

```
req.get('Content-Type');
```

These are all included the the [type definition for Express on Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts).

Comment: yes i know that, this was just an example (maybe not a good one). There are other headers that i'm interested in, not only accept

Comment: I have added an example for other headers.

Comment: Fair enough :) Your solution works, though i was more interested in "Declaration mergin". Thanks.

Comment: I agree, still looking for a solution on declaration merging myself